# Project Guidance - Chrome Extension to Synchronize Bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I am a newbie developer that thought of a project while in school.  I would like to create a Chrome extension that does the following:

- allows users to create a bookmark folder
- Allows users to create user groups with access to a specific folder
- Once an item is bookmarked in a user-shared folder, the page is
  visible as a bookmark to all users allowed in the folder

I am going through the Chrome extension guide on Google but I'm not sure of how to approach the pieces of this.  I would really appreciate if someone can help me break down what I need to create.

I am not worried if this has already been done, it's just something I'd really like to build over the summer.

Thanks!

---

Update:

users / research are telling me google doesn't allow you to talk / share content between users

In that case, what if I was to modify the idea such that if I bookmarked something, the extension brings up a pop-up box that allows me to email it to someone?  How would I break this down now?

Comment: As written, this seems to be a rather broad question.  But I'd recommend looking into a browser action with popup, in which case the only difficulty I see would be how to synchronize different extensions with the same data.  You may want to rephrase your question to focus on only the part you need to.

Comment: Your edit invalidates an existing answer - do not do that. Rather, since your question changes significantly, ask a new one. Also, how is the name of your project in the title helpful to others?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Chrome API does not provide tools for any interaction between users.

You *will* have to create your own server to handle this.

Then it stops to be a Chrome Extension specific question (except for the bookmark manipulation part, which is covered by [`chrome.bookmarks` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks))

Comment: hmm, what if I was to modify the idea.  So something simpler to the effect of:

When i bookmark something, I have a dialog box that pops up and allows me to send to to someone by email if I want to?